# Is it possible to automatically assign different list views to different groups of users in SharePoint Online?

Tags: sharepoint-online, permissions, list-view

I'm trying to create different views of a list in SharePoint Online for different groups of users. I tried Targeted Audience, but that will only let me create a single group of people to make a view for. I also need these views to work without a user having to input special data every time a new list item is created.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use Targeted Audience, we can create a SharePoint hosted add-in with client side web part and check the user permission using use REST API, then get the list items base on the permission using REST API with jQuery Ajax, and show the list items in a table.

Check the articles below:

[SharePoint 2013: How to Check User Permission with REST API](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/37392.sharepoint-2013-how-to-check-user-permission-with-rest-api.aspx)

[Using the SharePoint REST API in a SharePoint Add In](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1020972/Using-the-SharePoint-REST-API-in-a-SharePoint-Add)